What is the difference between hierarchical modeling and setting a (fixed) prior on a parameter?
I was reading through Chapter 11 of Data Analysis using Regression & Multilevel Models, and was confused by a slight variation of a simple hierarchical model posed in the text.
Lets say I have a dependent variable $y_i$, an independent variable $x_i$, and a group level status variable $\alpha_j$, $j=1, \cdots, m$ (e.g. country). Using the notation of the book, a possible regression model for this is:
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \alpha_{j[i]} + \epsilon_i,
$$
where $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and
$$
\alpha_j \sim N(0, \sigma^2_{\alpha}).
$$
Note that I impose the mean of the distribution of $\alpha_j$ is 0, because I include a global intercept $\beta_0$ in the model. If I were to fit this model in Stan, I would specify a prior on $\beta_0, \beta_1, \sigma^2$, and $\sigma^2_\alpha$.
However, I could also exogenously specify $\sigma^2_{\alpha}$ with some known value, rather than letting the model attempt to estimate it. This is no longer truly a hierarchical model, as $\alpha$ is no longer modeled, it just has a fixed prior.
I don't exactly understand what the implications of making this decision would be, and why I might prefer to do one or the other. Intuitively, it seems like the results should be relatively similar. Is there any guidance or intuition about the implications of this decision?
